# Conditional patch requests in RavenDB

Tags: indexing, nosql, patch, ravendb

How do I patch a document in RavenDB conditionally. The below code just patches all documents of type patron to Middle Initial = JJJ. I also would like to do this per condition.. for example .. do the same patch for the same Patrons documents types.. but for only those that have City ="New York"

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                                      new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:Patrons" },
                                      new[]
                                        {
                                             new PatchRequest
                                                 {
                                                     Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                                                     Name = "MiddleInitial",
                                                     Value = "JJJ"                                                           
                                                 }
                                            }, allowStale: false);
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: It seems that I've been wrong with this answer, because Ayende explains a way how to do it in his answer.**

This is something that cannot be done at the moment. However, Matt Warren has implemented something based on IronJS to do this stuff. I don't know when and if it will become part of the main product, but you can certainly use his Github repo if you really need it.

Instead, I suggest you either patch the documents on your own or don't denormalize the data and use .Include() instead if that's applicable in your case.

Comment: Is there no way to conditionally update fields in ravendb documents in bulk.. in that case.

Comment: Please see my response to Ayende's solution. Do you know if I can do the same if the values is nested two or three levels down? thank you

Comment: ZVenue, why don't you just try it out? To answer your question - yes, you can do that, exactly the way you wrote in your response. You don't need to car for NullReferenceExceptions here since RavenDB handles this for you.

Answer (score 3):

ZVenue,
You do it using:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Patrons/ByCity",
                                      new IndexQuery { Query = "City:\"New York\"" },
                                      new[]
                                        {
                                             new PatchRequest
                                                 {
                                                     Type = PatchCommandType.Set,
                                                     Name = "MiddleInitial",
                                                     Value = "JJJ"                                                           
                                                 }
                                            }, allowStale: false);
```

Where the Patrons/ByCity index is defined as:

```
from p in docs.Patrons select new { p.City }
```

Comment: If City value is nested inside the JSON.. can I just use this in the index? "from p in docs.patrons select new { p.Zone1.Country.City}"?